# How do I display two number text files correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  would to ask for solution regarding the file handling matter. The problem is when I try to print out the tuples from text file . Some digits or texts will be missing

Here's my code

```
        with open("ingredient.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f1:
            myarray = f1.readlines()

        with open("quantity.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f2:
            myarray2 = f2.readlines()  

        with open("demand.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f3:
            myarray3 = f3.readlines()


        for element1,element7,element0 in zip(myarray, myarray2, myarray3):
            element1 = element1[:-1]
            element7 = element7[:-1]
            element0 = element0[:-1]
            print(f'{element1:<35}{element7:<11}{element0:>7}')
```

File :
`demand.txt =  30,20,50`
`quantity.txt = 10,10,1`
`ingredient.txt= tomato,tomato,tomato`

What I got in my terminal is
`tomato 10 30`
`tomato 10 20`
`tomat      5` in parallel position

The outcome should be
`tomato 10 30`
`tomato 10 20`
`tomato  1 50`  in parallel position

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It makes it look like the contents of the files are a comma separated list, but then you use readlines() to read them in.  Are they comma separated or newline separated?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to post code; then use that technique to show us the terminal output and file contents, exactly as they appear for you.

Comment: @saquintes  Hi, they are separated in newline separated form.

Comment: If the files are as shown then that's not the output you'll get

Comment: @JCaesar  It is due to formatting problem , strip() works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's some ambiguity to your formatting, my guess is that the lines

```
element1 = element1[:-1]
element7 = element7[:-1]
element0 = element0[:-1]
```

are meant to strip the newlines off the end.  But the last element doesn't have a new line, so you get tomot instead of tomoto and you get nothing instead of 1.  I would suggest using `strip`.

```
element1 = element1.strip()
element7 = element7.strip()
element0 = element0.strip()
```

and see if that works better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a more compact way:

```
for e1, e2, e3 in zip(myarray, myarray2, myarray3):
    print(f'{e1.strip():<35}{e2.strip():<11}{e3.strip():>7}')
```